# Cannot serialize member.... because it is an interface

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have been having this problem and been pulling my hair out over it.  I have the followin error:

> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize member HannaPrintsDataAccess.Customer.CustomerAddresses of type System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[HannaPrintsDataAccess.CustomerAddress, HannaPrintsDataAccess, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an interface.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 196:        Customer customer = OperationsManager.Instance.CustomerService.GetCustomer(7);
>   Line 197:
>   Line 198:        string xml = OperationsManager.Instance.CustomerService.GetCustomerAddressesXml(CustomerAddress.FindAll());
>   Line 199:
>   Line 200:        Order order = OperationsManager.Instance.OrderService.CreateOrderFromCart(xml);
>
> Source File: c:\HostingSpaces\greetwus\galadavetiye.com\wwwroot\HannaPrints\HannaPrints\WebUI\CreateGreetingCard.aspx.cs    Line: 198
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize member HannaPrintsDataAccess.Customer.CustomerAddresses of type System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[HannaPrintsDataAccess.CustomerAddress, HannaPrintsDataAccess, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an interface.]
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Cannot serialize member 'HannaPrintsDataAccess.Customer.CustomerAddresses' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[HannaPrintsDataAccess.CustomerAddress, HannaPrintsDataAccess, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]', see inner exception for more details.]
>      System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.CheckSupportedMember(TypeDesc typeDesc, MemberInfo member, Type type) +889917
>      System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.GetPropertyModel(PropertyInfo propertyInfo) +132........

I have changed all my IList's to List's to see if that would do anything, but it didnt, infact, it didnt even take a second to load after making those changes, im guessing because the error happens even before it gets to that part.  I checked my remote files to see if it was uploading correctly and it was.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using Castle.ActiveRecord;
namespace HannaPrintsDataAccess { 
    public partial class Customer { 
        private IList _customerAddresses;


        public CustomerAddress GetPrimaryCustomerAddress()
        {
            foreach (CustomerAddress address in _customerAddresses)
            {
                if (address.IsPrimary)
                    return address;
            }
            return null;
        }


        [HasMany(typeof(CustomerAddress), ColumnKey = "CustomerId", Table = "Customer")]
        public virtual IList<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses
        {
            get
            {
                return this._customerAddresses;
            }
            set
            {
                this._customerAddresses = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error happens when this code is activated:

```
protected void orderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Customer customer = OperationsManager.Instance.CustomerService.GetCustomer(7);

    string xml = OperationsManager.Instance.CustomerService.GetCustomerAddressesXml(CustomerAddress.FindAll());

    Order order = OperationsManager.Instance.OrderService.CreateOrderFromCart(xml);
    OperationsManager.Instance.CartService.MoveCart("MyDesigns");

    Response.Redirect("~/Customer/PayByCreditCard.aspx?orderGuid=" + order.OrderGuid);
}
```

The CustomerAddress class:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Castle.ActiveRecord;


namespace HannaPrintsDataAccess
{
public partial class CustomerAddress
{
    public string ToXml()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(GetType());
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, this);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEnd();
    }

    [BelongsTo("CustomerId")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the code you posted, the type of `CustomerAddresses` is `IList<CustomerAdress>`. That's an interface. Like the error message says, you can't serialize an interface.

Comment: I understand that, but I tried changing it to normal List, but it gave me the SAME error, and I made sure code was uploaded and changed properly

Comment: @anthony: no, you didn't change it to a list and have it fail the same way. Sorry, you did something wrong. Probably something silly like leave the return value of the virtual property as `IList<T>` and just return `List<T>` from the override.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. When I do, "XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(kevinObject)" where kevinObject is an object with the attribute, [DataContract]. In kevinObject, there's a field, named "INewObject" because there are multiple implementations of INewObject. Is there a way to include an Interface that's marked [DataContract]?

Comment: This will help : http://theburningmonk.com/2010/05/net-tips-xml-serialize-or-deserialize-dictionary-in-csharp/

Answer (score 1):

In some circumstances, one might not be interested in serializing ALL fields of an object. In that case, the C# syntax to explicitly exclude a field from the serialization of an object is the following:

```
XmlAttributeOverrides attrOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes{ XmlIgnore = true };
attrOverrides.Add(type, member, attrs);   // "type" = type of the class that contains the member
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), attrOverrides);
[...]
```

For example, to exclude, e.g. for privacy reasons, the "Password" field from the serialization of an "obj" object we should write:

```
attrOverrides.Add(obj.GetType(), "Password", attrs);
```

For fields not declared directly in the object but inherited, the "type" parameter refers to the ancestor in which the field is declared. For example, to avoid, in an object that is a descendant of System.ComponentModel.Component, the error "*Cannot serialize member System.ComponentModel.Component.Site of type System.ComponentModel.ISite because it is an interface*", the syntax to use is:

```
attrOverrides.Add(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Component), "Site", attrs);
```

---

In general, the XMLSerializer cannot serialize an object of a class that exposes interface-type fields. Nevertheless, if someone still wants to serialize (with XMLSerializer) an object of this type (e.g. for log reasons) and has no problem ignoring fields of the interface type in serialization, the following function automatically ignores fields of this type (NB: of course the final result will NOT be the serialization of the initial object, but the serialization EXCLUDING the ignored parts, which is not the same thing):

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T obj, bool ignoreInterfaceTypeFields = false, List<Tuple<Type, string>> ignoreTypeList = null)
{
    string retValue = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        XmlAttributeOverrides attrOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes{ XmlIgnore = true };
        ignoreTypeList?.ForEach(t => attrOverrides.Add(t.Item1, t.Item2, attrs));    // ignore fields in ignoreTypeList
        
        if (ignoreInterfaceTypeFields)
        {
            foreach (var t in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (t.PropertyType.IsInterface)
                    if (attrOverrides[t.DeclaringType, t.Name] is null)
                        attrOverrides.Add(t.DeclaringType, t.Name, attrs);    // ignore interface type fields
            }
        }

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), attrOverrides);
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
                retValue = sw.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
    
    return retValue;
}


// declared in non-generic, non-nested static classes
public static string Serialize<T>(this T obj, bool ignoreInterfaceTypeFields = false, List<Tuple<Type, string>> ignoreTypeList = null)
{
    return Serialize<T>(obj, ignoreInterfaceTypeFields, ignoreTypeList);
}
```

---

This Serialize method can be called without params:

```
sClient = client.Serialize();
```

or manually excluding unwanted fields:

```
var ignoreTypeList = new List<Tuple<Type, string>>
{
    new Tuple<Type, string>(client.GetType(), "Password"),                       // unwanted field (directly declared in "Client" class)
    new Tuple<Type, string>(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Component), "Site")     // unwanted field (declared in "System.ComponentModel.Component" ancestor class of "Client" class)
};

sClient = client.Serialize(false, ignoreTypeList);
```

or excluding unwanted fields AND interface type fields:

```
var ignoreTypeList = new List<Tuple<Type, string>>
{
    new Tuple<Type, string>(client.GetType(), "Password")                        // unwanted field (directly declared in "Client" class)
};

sClient = client.Serialize(true, ignoreTypeList);
```

---

NOTE: with framework 4.7.2 or later (or using System.ValueTuple nuget) the syntax of Tuples can be made more readable:

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T obj, bool ignoreInterfaceTypeFields = false, List<(Type type, string member)> ignoreTypeList = null)
```

and:

```
var ignoreTypeList = new List<(Type, string)> 
{
    new (client.GetType(), "Password"),                        
    new (typeof(System.ComponentModel.Component), "Site")
};
```

Comment: A couple comments: 1) `XmlTextWriter` is deprecated, Microsoft suggests to use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.  2) If you manufacture an `XmlSerializer` using the `new XmlSerializer(Type, XmlAttributeOverrides)` constructor, you ***must*** cache it statically and reuse it to prevent a severe memory leak (creating and loading multiple duplicate runtime-generated DLLs).  See: [Memory Leak using StreamReader and XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23897145/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

Following options fail with XML serializer:

```
public IList<CustomerAddresses> CustomerAddresses  { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<CustomerAddresses> CustomerAddresses  { get; set; }
```

Use array like below:

```
public CustomerAddresses[] CustomerAddresses { get; set; }
```

Following works but not SONAR/Quality complaint:

```
public List<CustomerAddresses> CustomerAddresses  { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [XmlIgnore] Annotation if you want to use your property without serializing it.

Answer (score -2):

Not the source of your problem, but you need

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, this);
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: How will that work if `serializer` is an XmlSerializer created as the user has stated and the type can't be serialized?