# Cannot deserialize an IComparable field for value types

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have investigated an issue around binary serialization of a IComparable property which causes the following error when the IComparable property is assigned a DateTime:

Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader.

The following code can produce this issue:

```
/// <summary>
/// This class is injected with an icomparable object, which is assigned to a property.
/// If serialized then deserializes using binary serialization, an exception is thrown
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public class SomeClassNotWorking
{
    public SomeClassNotWorking(IComparable property)
    {
        Property = property;
    }

    public IComparable Property;

}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // var comparable = new SomeClass<DateTime>(DateTime.Today);
        // here we pass in a datetime type that inherits IComparable (ISerializable also produces the error!!)
        var instance = new SomeClassNotWorking(DateTime.Today);

        // now we serialize
        var bytes = BinaryHelper.Serialize(instance);
        BinaryHelper.WriteToFile("serialisedResults", bytes);

        // then deserialize
        var readBytes = BinaryHelper.ReadFromFile("serialisedResults");
        var obj = BinaryHelper.Deserialize(readBytes);
    }
}
```

I have resolved the issue by replacing the IComparable property with a type T property which implements IComparable:

```
/// <summary>
/// This class contains a generic type property which implements IComparable
/// This serializes and deserializes correctly without error
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
[Serializable]
public class SomeClass<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public SomeClass(T property)
    {
        Property = property;
    }

    public T Property;
}
```

This serializes and de-serializes without problems.  However, why would serialization of an IComparable property (when that property is a DateTime) cause the issue in the first place, particularly as DateTime supports IComparable?  This also happens with ISerializable.

Comment: It probably is directly related to the fact that you cannot create an instance of an interface.

Comment: @Bob2Chiv it works when he provides his implementation of IComparable. It's a known bug.

Comment: @Adriano Interesting, I thought it was because you can serialize an instance of T, but not an instance of IComparable; even if there is a concrete value associated with it, like in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632769/cannot-serialize-member-because-it-is-an-interface). Very nice to know about this bug, however.

Comment: @Bob2Chiv I still don't understand why it has not been fixed! I guess for compatibility but I can't imagine how. Anyway it _seems_ to happen only for value types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known bug and it's not fixed: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/91177/de-serialization-of-an-instance-of-a-class-implementing-icomparable-does-not-work

Comment: Different value types produce different results / exceptions.  If I pass in an int rather than a DateTime I get the following error - SerializationException - End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed.

Comment: @mmd yes maybe it depends on how the data is being deserialized but I agree, it's a very _stupid_ thing...

Comment: A known bug with inconsistent results is not very helpful!  Shame that there is no planned fix and that the work involved outweighs the benefits.  @Adriano - Thanks for the info and link.